# Prism AnimatedTabControl customization

Tags: wpf, prism

---

I have a user interface like Prism StockTrader RI application with some changes whrere
  i put control panel in ResearchRegion contains list of items when i select one item
   its details are displayed in the  AnimatedTabControl in the main region.
I need to customize the AnimatedTabControl (from StockTrader RI) like this:

- The AnimatedTabControl  show tab header like normal tab control where header 
      will contain the selected item name
- When new selection is applied from a control panel that resides in the ResearchRegion a 
     new tab open w/o removing the previous tab selection and w/o animation
- Tab header contain close button to close any of the open tabs when required
- Animation take place only when changing the control panel in the ResearchRegion

  ```
   public class AnimatedTabControl : TabControl
  {
      public static readonly RoutedEvent SelectionChangingEvent =     EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
          "SelectionChanging", RoutingStrategy.Direct, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof (AnimatedTabControl));

      private DispatcherTimer timer;

      public AnimatedTabControl()
      {
          DefaultStyleKey = typeof(AnimatedTabControl);
      }

      public event RoutedEventHandler SelectionChanging
      {
          add { AddHandler(SelectionChangingEvent, value); }
          remove { RemoveHandler(SelectionChangingEvent, value); }
      }

      protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
      {
          this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
              (Action)delegate
              {
                  this.RaiseSelectionChangingEvent();

                  this.StopTimer();

                  this.timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0,     500) };

                  EventHandler handler = null;
                  handler = (sender, args) =>
                  {
                      this.StopTimer();
                      base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
                  };
                  this.timer.Tick += handler;
                  this.timer.Start();
              });
      }

      // This method raises the Tap event
      private void RaiseSelectionChangingEvent()
      {
          var args = new RoutedEventArgs(SelectionChangingEvent);
          RaiseEvent(args);
      }

      private void StopTimer()
      {
          if (this.timer != null)
          {
              this.timer.Stop();
              this.timer = null;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I have answered part#3 of your question(Tab header contain close button to close any of the open tabs when required).

Have a look at my public folder in SkyDrive Account:-
(https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=656548C49A72B6CD!105)